# How can i setup unity catalog in databricks?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, metastore

how can i setup unity catalog in azure databricks from azure portal, setting up from metastore, containers

I have created premium azure databricks workspace but still unable to link metastore to it to run unity catalog.

Answer (score 0):

What error you have, where you stucked ?

I followed this instruction (it is nicely written):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/get-started

It is important that you need Global Administrator role in Azure or someone with this role who can granted you Account admin role here:
https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net/login/

Comment: There is no option in databricks workspace to "Create Metastore".

Comment: metastore is created not from the workspace, but from the Databricks account console

Comment: @AlexOtt is righ, James metastore can be created from this portal: https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net/data If you haven't got access you need to follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/get-started#requirements

Comment: @AlexOtt yes but there is no option to "create metastore" in Databricks Account console, i am also following the azure documentation.

Comment: @James https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net/data You should have blue button that creates metastore